# How much does storage increase when I add an instance to an Amazon Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

When you're running out of space on an Amazon Elasticsearch cluster the documentation recommends: "If you are not using EBS, add additional nodes to your cluster configuration."

source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/add-storage-elasticsearch/

But I'm not able to find any explanation as to "how much" does that increase the storage? Does it literally *double* the storage going from one instance to two?

Tangential follow-up: When you add another instance to a cluster does it automatically re-balance the existing indexes or do you have to rebuild them?

Answer (score 1):

If you go from one instance to two, you double the storage, indeed. Try that and see if it solves your storage space issue.

Regarding your follow-up question, when new nodes join the cluster, ES will automatically rebalance the shards to the new nodes. Automatic rebalancing is one of ES' nicest features.

Comment: Anything else needed?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if the default elasticsearch index configuration is 1 primary plus 1 replica, the cluster will automatically replicate all your shards, and consume all your added disk space. Check the AES docs, and your instance configs.